# Opengl 2d resizing

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d

My origin is not at top left corner, when I resize my window. And the 2d coordinates are not in pixel coordinates:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
rnd::initDraw();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0, mainPanelx, mainPanely, 0.0, -1.0, 10.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
//glPushMatrix();        ----Not sure if I need this
glLoadIdentity();
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(10.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(10.0, 10.0);
    glVertex2f(0.0, 10.0);
glEnd();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glutSwapBuffers();
```

Resize function:

```
void resize(int width, int height)
{
if (height == 0) height = 1;

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

/* note we divide our width by our height to get the aspect ratio */
gluPerspective(45.0, width / height, 1.0, 400.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
mainPanelx = width;
mainPanely = height;
std::cout<<mainPanelx<<", "<<mainPanely<<"\n";
}
```

How do i get the origin constant at the top left corner of my window and how do i get the 2d coordinates in pixel coordinates?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your resize function should probably call [`glViewport(0, 0, width, height)`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glViewport.xml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call [`glViewport`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glViewport.xml) in your resize function.

This means OpenGL will still render to the old sized viewport.